# Is "magnum" a valid word to cover "big"?

Tags: synonyms, slang

This word is mostly unusual to use in speaking, so here my question.

Magnum comes from 1788 in English as "large wine-bottle," usually containing two quarts. As the name of a powerful type of handgun, registered 1935 by Smith & Wesson Inc., of Springfield, Massachusetts. Magnum opus "masterpiece, a person's greatest work," is literally "great work"

Comment: Do any dictionary example sentences match this suggested interchangeability with 'big'? ...  What do you suspect?

Comment: Please could you provide an example sentence so we know the context?

Comment: I thought it was an ice cream.

Comment: @David fun fact: I know the person who invented the ice cream magnum. Unfortunately not the champagne magnum too. :(

Comment: *Great* (in *great work*) does not mean *big*. And *magnum* is not used as a normal word on its own either.

Answer (score -2):

No, it isn't a commonly used word in English. I think that you could use it if you were exaggerating something in a comical sense, though. Eg. Magnum dong.

Comment: How is the poster or anyone else to know whether you are right or not?  Please read the help on answering questions.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the feedback!